# NextAuth Cookie not being set in production

Tags: cookies, next-auth

I have a React + Nextjs application which uses NextAuth. I'm trying to set a refresh token in a cookie which works fine on localhost but doesn't work when deployed on to production (HTTPS). The function setting the cookie is shown below. Is there something that I've missed?

From `[...nextauth].ts`:

```
const setRefreshTokenCookie = (
  cookies: Cookies,
  refresh_token: string
): Cookies => {
  const date = new Date();
  const time = date.getTime();
  const expireTime = time + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 * 90; // 90 days
  date.setTime(expireTime);

  const currentCookies = cookies.set(
    `${useSecureCookies ? "__Host-" : ""}test.refresh-token`,
    refresh_token,
    {
      sameSite: "strict",
      overwrite: true,
      expires: date,
      httpOnly: useSecureCookies,
    }
  );
  return currentCookies ;
};
```

**Notes:**

NextAuth's [useSecureCookie](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/options)

**localhost cookies:**

- test.csrf-token
- test.refresh-token
- test.callback-url
- test.session-token

**production cookies:**

- __Host-test.csrf-token
- __Secure-test.callback-url
- __Secure-test.session-token

Comment: were you able to resolve this issue?